# Extension of Cauchy sequentially regular function

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, metric-spaces

To prove:

> If $A$ is a subset of a metric space $(X,d)$ and there is a function $f$ from $A$ to a complete metric space $(Y,e)$ which maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy. Then there exists a unique continuous extension of the function to the closure of $A$.

I defined the function to the closure of $A$ in the most natural way like if $x$ belongs to the closure, let $(x_n)$ a sequence in $A$, converge to $x$. Hence, it is cauchy and hence $f(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $Y$ and therefore converge to some $y$. Call this $y$ to be the image of our new function.

I face problem in proving it continuous.

Comment: $f$ is continuous because for all $x$ in the closure of $A$, for all sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $A$ converging to $x$, $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$. To show this, use that $(f(x_n) )_n$ is Cauchy.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$Before worrying about whether it’s continuous, you need to prove that it’s well-defined. That is, you must show that if $p\in\cl A$, and $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ are sequence in $A$ converging to $p$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(y_n)$.

HINT: Consider the sequence $\langle z_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle=\langle x_0,y_0,x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,\dots\rangle$ defined by setting $z_{2n}=x_n$ and $z_{2n+1}=y_n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$.

Let $\hat f:\cl A\to Y$ be the extension of $f$ that you’ve defined; I’ll get you started on a proof that $\hat f$ is continuous. Since $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces, you can show that $\hat f$ is continuous by showing that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a convergent sequence in $\cl A$ with limit $x$, then $\langle\hat f(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $\hat f(x)$ in $Y$. Suppose not; then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $M=\left\{n\in\Bbb N:e\big(\hat f(x_n),\hat f(x)\big)\ge\epsilon\right\}$ is infinite.

If $\{n\in M:x_n\in A\}$ is infinite, we get an immediate contradiction with the definition of $\hat f$ (why?), so we may assume that $M_0=\{n\in M:x_n\in\cl A\setminus A\}$ is infinite. Show that if $n\in M_0$, there is a $\delta_n>0$ such that $e\big(\hat f(z),\hat f(x_n)\big)>\frac{\epsilon}2$ whenever $z\in A\cap B(x_n,\delta_n)$, and choose $z_n\in A$ so that $d(x_n,z_n)<\min\{2^{-n},\delta_n\}$. (As usual, $B(y,r)$ is the open ball of radius $r$ centred at $y$.)

Finally, show that $\langle z_n:n\in M\rangle$ is a sequence in $A$ converging to $x$, and derive a contradiction.